# Curve behavior of derivative

Tags: derivatives, curves

I wonder whether there is a possibility to check how the derivative of a function behaves.

Taking the following as example:

[image: img]

I notice that in the first and last region, the curve is increasing but the derivative behaves differently there. For the first, it is decreasing and for the latter it is increasing.
Or is there a pattern I don't see?

Comment: and by only eyeballing at it?

Answer (score 1):

Concavity of the graph. The derivative is decreasing as function is concave downwards and increasing as it is concave upwards.